# Is this a good attempt at database normalization?

Tags: database, database-design, ms-access

I have a database dealing with people who have had different types of injuries categorized based on a score.  For instance, there are tests like below:

admit pain, discharge pain, home pain
admit memory, discharge memory, home memory

Every one of these tests goes 1-7.  Right now I have my tables set up like this:

**Main table**

```
first name, last name  
SSN  
address  
etc.  
pain FK (foreign key)  
memory FK (foreign key)
```

**Pain table**

```
autonum PK  
admit  
discharge  
home
```

**Memory table**

```
autonum PK  
admit  
discharge  
home
```

Is this correctly normalized?  Or should I have tables of admit, discharge and home with pain and memory parts of those tables?

Comment: okay, that didn't format like i wanted so it's not nearly as easy to read.  an even bigger thanks if someone can make some sense of it!

Comment: There you go. Some good reading over here to help with that: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Would you have other types of tests that could be added later?  You could create a test table with test type (Pain, Memory, etc), test sequence (admit, discharge, home, etc), Patient FK and score. I do not see a score in any of your tables.  You also need a key for your main table and SSN should not be used as a key for medical information.

Comment: yes, there are actually more tests than just pain and memory.  but i didn't want to make it so cumbersome.  there are ~20 different tests.  so i think i got ya. i need a test table (with all the names of the tests as fields) the test sequence as fields (admit, discharge home) and score?  so i don't need to break the tests into separate tables?  i know not to use ssn as PKs.  but you can never beat the privacy horse too much :p

Comment: I would think a test might have additional information like measurement date/time and maybe who performed the test?  Medical testing databases like this get very general and become something like an Entity/Attribute/Value (EAV) database.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your existing structure is that you can only have one entry in the pain table and one entry in the memory table for each patient.  My guess is that these test will be run multiple times.  Perhaps an alternate structure that would also allow for additional tests might look something like this:

**Main Table**
autonum PK
first name
last name
SSN
address
etc.

**Tests Results Table**
autonum PK
Date
Patient ID (FK to main table)
test Type id (FK to tests table)
test result

**Tests Table**
autonum PK
Testname

If you need additional data on each test this design would have to be modified a bit.  But based on your question this will allow you t store multiple tests and test results for each person

Answer (score 1):

Aren't the Pain and Memory tables the same table with a record type?

**Test table**

```
autonum PK  
typeID  FK       (Pain/memory)
admit  
discharge  
home
```

**Test Types table**

```
autonum typeID   PK
description
```

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean by record type?  yes, the tables would be identical except for their type.  so i need a test table with admit, discharge, home and score?  And then have a table of all the different test types, right?